# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" when deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my application to Heroku and when I am getting to a certain page my application gives an internal server error. It is super weird; sometimes it just works when I deploy, and sometimes it gives me this error.

Code:

```
const storage = require('../modules/storage')

module.exports = (req, res) => {

// Unique user code
givenCode = req.body.uniqueCode

// new empty object for the given code.
const newObj = {
    code: givenCode,
    personal: {
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        age: "",
        gender: "",
        favoriteGame: "",
    },
    "game_personal": {
        favoritePlatform: "",
        averageGameTime: "",
        prefer: "",
        favoriteGameGenre: "",
        gamertag: "",
    },
    "open_questions": {
        favoriteGameOfAllTime: "",
        whatWouldYouDo: "",
        intoVideoGames: "",
    },
    "rate_game": {
        opinionAboutTheGame: "",
        rate: "",
        timeSpend: "",
        recommend: "",
    },
}

// takes the object and adds it to a json file in the storage map with the unique code as name
storage.saveNewData(newObj, `./storage/${givenCode}.json`)

res.render('personal', { 
    uniqueCode: givenCode,
})
```

It goes wrong on this line:

```
storage.saveNewData(newObj, `./storage/${givenCode}.json`)
```

Storage code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
    // Checks if the file exists and gives back an boolean
    checksIfFileExists: path => fs.existsSync(path),
    // Gets the data if it exists and parse it to an object. the readFileSync 
    // reads the contents of the path synchronously with an extra option for utf-8
    getExistingData: path => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        flag:'r',
    })),
    // Will save the new data to the path when it is submitted. Also turns the data
    // it into a JSON string and after that returns it. The extra parameters give a good
    // formatted JSON file
    saveNewData: (data, path) => {
        fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
        return data
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912533+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './storage/b0abd8a8.json'
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912538+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912539+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1467:35)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912539+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.saveNewData (/app/modules/storage.js:16:12)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912540+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/routes/personal.js:39:13)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912540+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912541+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912541+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912542+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912542+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2021-03-30T19:11:31.912543+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

I am a beginner developer.